# Filter xts objects by common dates

Tags: r, time-series, xts, quantmod

I am stuck with the following code.

For reference the code it is taken from the following website (http://gekkoquant.com/2013/01/21/statistical-arbitrage-trading-a-cointegrated-pair/), I am also compiling the code through R Studio.

```
library("quantmod")

startDate = as.Date("2013-01-01")
symbolLst<-c("WPL.AX","BHP.AX")

symbolData <- new.env() 
getSymbols(symbolLst, env = symbolData, src = "yahoo", from = startDate)

stockPair <- list(
   a =coredata(Cl(eval(parse(text=paste("symbolData$\"",symbolLst[1],"\"",sep="")))))
  ,b = coredata(Cl(eval(parse(text=paste("symbolData$\"",symbolLst[2],"\"",sep="")))))
  ,hedgeRatio = 0.70   ,name=title)

spread <- stockPair$a - stockPair$hedgeRatio*stockPair$b
```

I am getting the following error.

```
Error in stockPair$a - stockPair$hedgeRatio * stockPair$b : 
      non-conformable arrays
```

The reason these particular series don't match is because "WPL.AX" has an extra value (date:19-05-2014 - the matrix lengths are different) compared to "BHP". How can I solve this issue when loading data?

I have also tested other stock pairs such as "ANZ","WBC" with the source = "google" which produces two of the same length arrays.

```
> length(stockPair$a)
[1] 360
> length(stockPair$b)
[1] 359
```

Comment: You need to find why the dimensions differ, not try to force them to be the same.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg sorry let me re-phrase myself, the reason these particular series don't match is because "WPL.AX" has an extra value (date:19-05-2014) compared to "BHP". How can I solve this issue when when loading data?

Comment: Please state this in the question, instead of, "How would I force R to conform the two arrays."

Comment: @MatthewLundberg I have updated my question appropriately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add code such as this prior to the `stockPair` computation, to trim each `xts` set to the intersection of dates:

```
common_dates <- as.Date(Reduce(intersect, eapply(symbolData, index)))
symbolData <- eapply(symbolData, `[`, i=common_dates)
```

Comment: Note that `[` ignores argument names and only uses positional matching, so the `i=` in `i=common_dates` is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine if you don't convert your xts object to matrix via `coredata`. Then `Ops.xts` will ensure that only the rows with the same index will be subtracted. And `fortune(106)` applies.

```
fortunes::fortune(106)
# If the answer is parse() you should usually rethink the question.
#    -- Thomas Lumley
#       R-help (February 2005)

stockPair <- list(
   a = Cl(symbolData[[symbolLst[1]]])
  ,b = Cl(symbolData[[symbolLst[2]]])
  ,hedgeRatio = 0.70
  ,name = "title")
spread <- stockPair$a - stockPair$hedgeRatio*stockPair$b
```

Here's an alternative approach:

```
# merge stocks into a single xts object
stockPair <- do.call(merge, eapply(symbolData, Cl))
# ensure stockPair columns are in the same order as symbolLst, since
# eapply may loop over the environment in an order you don't expect
stockPair <- stockPair[,pmatch(symbolLst, colnames(stockPair))]
colnames(stockPair) <- c("a","b")
# add hedgeRatio and name as xts attributes
xtsAttributes(stockPair) <- list(hedgeRatio=0.7, name="title")
spread <- stockPair$a - attr(stockPair,'hedgeRatio')*stockPair$b
```